# Using Distortion Coefficients with findHomography in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, distortion

I  am currently lost in the OpenCV documentation and am looking for some guidance on the possible ordering of functions, or perhaps a function within OpenCV that I haven't came acrossed yet...

I am tracking a laser blob within a camera feed to a location on a projection screen. Up until now I have been using findHomography and then projectTransform to accomplish this however the camera I was using had very little distortion. Now I am using a different camera with a noticeable radial distortion. I have used cvCalibrateCamera to get the distortion coefficients, camera matrix, etc. but I am not sure how I should use this data with my current process, or perhaps I need to use different functions and/or ordering of functions from OpenCV altogether. Any suggestions would be appreciated...

My current code that works well (without distortion) is as follows:

```
Mat homog;
homog = findHomography(Mat(vCameraPoints), Mat(vTargetPoints), CV_RANSAC);

vector<Point2f> cvTrackPoint;
cvTrackPoint.push_back(Point2f(pMapPoint.fX, pMapPoint.fY));                        

Mat normalizedImageMat;
perspectiveTransform(Mat(cvTrackPoint), normalizedImageMat, homog);

Point2f normalizedImgPt;
normalizedImgPt = Point2f(normalizedImageMat.at<Point2f>(0,0));
normalizedImgPt.x /= szCameraSize.fWidth;
normalizedImgPt.y /= szCameraSize.fHeight;
```

I then of course multiply the normalizedImgPt to my projection screen resolution

So again, just to clarify...I do have what appears to be good data from calibrateCamera, how would I use this information to factor in the lens distortion? Perhaps the above process wont work, any help?

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have acquired the distortion coefficients, then a simple (yet probably suboptimal) way to get back to the non-distorted case would be to undistort the image. The undistorted image is the image a camera with similar intrinsic and extrinsic parameters but without lens distorsion would acquire. 
The corresponding OpenCV function is [`undistort`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistort)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I understand what you are saying however actually undistorting the image wont help me much as the camera feed isnt actually be shown during normal operation. I was really hoping for a function like projectPoints or undistortPoints. I will know the x/y within feed/ROI and just need to apply the distort values to the know x/y so it will be correct, etc. 

However, those functions mentioned above project from the object space to the image space of the camera. Also, how does findHomography fit in or does it if the above functions did work?

Comment: Well, I guess I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish then, would you care explaining it in greater details ? Because there is an `undistortPoints` function that also seem to accomplish what I think you want. Additionnaly, I don't understand why whether or not the camera feed is shown during normal operation matters.